# Getting data from XML in SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<APIDATA xmlns="api-com">
<ORDER EngineID="1" OrderID="66"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="27" SeqID="17"/></ORDER>
<ORDER EngineID="2" OrderID="67"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="28" SeqID="18"/></ORDER>
</APIDATA>
```

I would like to get all IDs to SSIS variables in a for each loop for all Order entries. So far I can get the first two id with a ForeachLoop in control flow in SSIS, with the following:

```
EnumerationType:  ElementCollection
OuterXPathString: //*[name() = 'ORDER']
InnerElementType: NodeText
InnerXPathString: @*
```

Then on variable mappings I use two string variables with index 0 and 1, to get the two IDs. How can I get the INSTSPECIFIER element's ID? What would be the correct XPath command for getting all four IDs in one go?

Note, there can only be one INSTSPECIFIER in the ORDER element. Also in case this needs to be done seperately, like getting the ORDER in the ForeachLoop and getting the INSTSPECIFIER in an XMLTask, the OrderID is the primary key. So in this case, the question is, how can I get in an XMLTask the InstID and SeqID of a INSTSPECIFIER entry, that has a parent ORDER entry with a specific OrderID?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time try four variables and InnerXPathString: `@* | child::node()/@*` Other values without change.

Comment: I have tried this approach, but I get an error through the mapping. It seems, I cannot index, but 0 and 1 (the number of elements in ORDER). If I try to map VariableInstID to 2 I get an error: 

`Error: The enumerator failed to retrieve element at index "2".`

How can I map correctly in this situation?

Comment: @user1348490 hard to say. I've got ssis 2012, [4 string variables](http://i.imgur.com/vo5gH.png) with [default mapping](http://i.imgur.com/e5wM1.png), your [xml as source](http://i.imgur.com/m2jPB.png), [properties configured](http://i.imgur.com/MMVAA.png) as i've written and everything is fine: [first iteration](http://i.imgur.com/r1mel.png) and [second](http://i.imgur.com/YkTCC.png).

Comment: Getting close. Some null handling problem remains. The xml is a bit more complicated. Your answer works though I managed to get some fields.

Comment: I figured it out, that error comes from the actual xml has different length lines. If you can help me yet an other time here is the [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175561/xml-indexing-in-ssis-with-different-length). Thanks in advance.