# XML indexing in SSIS with different length

Tags: xml, ssis

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<APIDATA xmlns="api-com">
<ORDER EngineID="1" OrderID="66" OtherInfo="yes"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="27" SeqID="17"/></ORDER>
<ORDER EngineID="2" OrderID="67" OtherInfo="yes"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="28" SeqID="18"/></ORDER>
<ORDER EngineID="3" OrderID="68"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="29" SeqID="19"/></ORDER>
</APIDATA>
```

I would like to get all IDs to SSIS variables in a for each loop for all Order entries. So far I can get data with a ForeachLoop in control flow in SSIS, with the following:

```
EnumerationType:  ElementCollection
OuterXPathString: //*[name() = 'ORDER']
InnerElementType: NodeText
InnerXPathString: @* | child::node()/@*
```

Then on variable mappings I come accross the problem, that the lines of the XML are not the same length. E.g.: the third line does not have an OtherInfo entry. This causes the loop to die with error if I map a variable to index 4.

What is the solution to this problem?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time use `@*[name() = 'EngineID'] | @*[name() = 'OrderID']  | child::node()/@*[name() = 'InstID'] | child::node()/@*[name() = 'SeqID']` as InnerXPathString.

Comment: Thanks, this is the way to do it.